# How do I get one monitor in landscape and one monitor in portrait mode on Ubuntu 9.04?

Tags: ubuntu, x11

I'm running Ubuntu 9.04 (Jaunty), and I have a nVidia 8600GTS graphics card.
I'm trying to get one monitor to work in portrait mode, and the other one in landscape mode. I know how to do this under Windows, but I can't find the setting for this under Linux. I've managed to get them both in portrait, or both in landscape, but not independant of each other.

I'd like to be able to switch modes for a single monitor without restarting the computer or X, but I realise that might be a bit too much too ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will depend on whether your graphics card driver supports it (if you advise what card you have then we can confirm this) but.

```
xrandr --output <output> --rotate <direction>
```

should do it.

Check out

```
man xrandr
```

here is excerpt from the EXAMPLES section

```
Sets an output called LVDS to its preferred mode, and on its right put an output called VGA to preferred mode of a screen which has
   been physically rotated clockwise:
          xrandr --output LVDS --auto --rotate normal --pos 0x0 --output VGA --auto --rotate left --right-of LVDS
```

*Note that this does not work when using the nvidia binary driver, see comment for alternative solution*

Comment: I mentioned the card (nVidia 8600GTS) in my question. Do you know if it supports this?

Comment: Apologies, not quite sure how I missed that.. Currently it's not possible to use twinview with xrandr (and have xrandr see it as 2 separate monitors). 

However check out the xorg.conf in the 2nd post on this page which might help you get what you want: http://tinyurl.com/cnrgwh

You will have to restart to apply these settings though